# Use two network interfaces simultaneously

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, network-interface

I often use Wi-Fi from some public networks which don't allow some protocols (like torrent or IRC - next I will only speak about IRC). If I want to use one of those protocols, I have to use my phone 3G connection (through the `usb0` interface).

I'd like to stay connected to the Wi-Fi for my web navigation (so use the classical `wlan0` interface), but use another interface (here `usb0`) for some softwares (often only for weechat, a CLI IRC client).

Thus I have two (linked) questions :

- how to simultaneously connect to two interfaces without all messing things up ?
- how to configure one software to use an interface, and another software to use the other interface ? As weechat is a CLI software, maybe I just have to declare a specific environment variable ; but how to be sure that Firefox doesn't use `usb0` instead of `wlan0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have two separate routing tables; one of them (`wlan0`, in your case) will be the default one, while we can use a neat trick to force a specific application to use the non-default table.

First, create two tables (substitute NAME1 with a name making sense to you, same thing with IP1, DEV1, and so on):

```
echo 201 NAME2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add a gateway to each routing table (if needed):

```
ip route add NET1 dev DEV1 src SRC1 table main
ip route add NET2 dev DEV2 src SRC2 table NAME2
```

Then a default route:

```
ip route add default via IP1 table main
ip route add default via IP2 table NAME2
```

Then the rules to select the route table based on the source address:

```
ip rule add from IP1 table main
ip rule add from IP2 table NAME2
```

Now we need to force `weechat` to use IP2.We do so by building [a new bind module](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html). It is trivial to do so, there are simple instructions in the reference. Once you have compiled the module and placed in `/usr/lib`, you issue the command:

```
 BIND_ADDR=IP2 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/bind.so weechat
```

and you are done. The advantage of this is that it can be easily scripted, and can be repeated for as many applications as you like.

Comment: looks promising but something in routes/tables isn't enough...

Answer (score 2):

If you define two sub-networks, for example:

- 192.168.1.x / 255.255.255.0 - `wlan0`
- 192.168.2.x / 255.255.255.0 - `usb0`

If you define gateway only for `wlan0`, all network traffic beside addressed directly to 192.168.2.x goes through `wlan0`.

You can route  network traffic to specific IP addresses through you `usb0` interface. You can also [route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux).

Comment: The sentence `You can route network traffic to specific IP addresses through your  usb0 interface` is wrong. If you only have one gateway, on the **other** interface, how can you route to any given WAN addresses on the `usb0` interface? You barely mention **a** solution.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae man route -> gw GW -> "If  you specify the address of one of your local interfaces, it will be used to decide about the interface to which the packets should be  routed  to.".

Comment: Just try it, see whether it works. I did a few hours ago, it did not.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I haven't see your route command, I don't know you network configuration... Try to ask a question then :P  Yes your answer is better and even I - in opposition to you - upvoted you.