# Opensuse: Force Kmail to use wireless connection while rest of the programs use wired connection

Tags: networking, email, kde, opensuse, kmail

I live in college dorm and I am using OpenSuse Leap 42.1 with KDE. I want to use KMail for accessing my college email server. I am usually connect via ethernet connection because it is almost 10 times faster than WiFi. But the problem is that my college has blocked the incoming port(993) and outgoing SMTP port(587). So, I cannot retrieve or send email while in wired connection. However, those ports are open if I use WiFi and I can both send and receive email when I am in WiFi. But WiFi sucks and I don't want to use it for other purposes. So, my question is can I configure my network settings or my KMail setting so that KMail uses WiFi connection while rest of the applications use wired ethernet connection?

Comment: Have they blocked ports 25 and 143? You could try those instead. Ensure that you enable `starttls` in your KMail settings for the accounts otherwise you'll be unencrypted.

Comment: They have blocked both of the ports 25 and 143. The only solution I can see right now is to use wireless for email and use wired connection for everything else. I'm not an advanced user. So, I had to ask here.

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux