# How to set Chrome NOT to use OpenVPN?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, vpn, openvpn

I connect to the internet via `openvpn`. I want all the traffic through the VPN except Google Chrome/Chromium. How can I set the Chrome NOT to use the system proxy?

Answer (score 1):

If you have **only** some proxy working in your virtual network and the system is configured to use it as default you can change it in browser preferences (first link found in google: http://googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-advanced-settings/Google-chrome-proxy-settings.html ) or start chrome browser with unset environment variable (one line):

```
http_proxy="" google-chrome
```

But, I think that by "system proxy" you mean something different - redirecting all the traffic via VPN. This is not proxy (the server that your browser connect to, and this server connects to websites), but it is system configuration of network routing. And it makes almost impossible to configure only the traffic from/to one specific application to be routed out of VPN. Theoretically you could try packet marking and advanced routing techniques to do this. But it is not worth effort.

**Update**

This may be helpful: [Route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux)