# IP addresses and Shadowsocks proxy issues

Tags: proxy, ip

I have a server on which I installed [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html) (a socks 5 proxy) with 2 public IP addresses.

When I use public IP address 1 to connect to the server, then I use "What is my IP?" in Google to test my current IP, it shows IP 1.

However, when I use IP 2 to connect server's proxy, the test IP websites still shows IP 1 (I want it to think of me as IP 2 to visit the aim website).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

"What is my IP?" shows IP 1 because your server connects to that site via IP 1, i.e. your server uses IP 1 as the default routing to the Internet.

You should already have 2 ss server processes receiving traffic from 2 IPs, then you need to route traffic from one of them to IP 1, another to IP 2.

What you need to learn is how to route based on process, using namespace is an option to do that: 
[Route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux)