# iptables cgroup module not found with Kernel 4.19.118-v7l+ and iptables v1.8.2

Tags: iptables

I try to do a routing on a per process basis like described here
[Route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux/1048913) and here https://www.evolware.org/?p=369

However when I try to execute

`iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j MARK --set-mark 11`

I get

```
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `cgroup':No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

This system is on Raspbian/Debian Buster Kernel 4.19.118-v7l+

Has the syntax changed or why isn't this working?

Comment: I seem to have the same problem when trying this on a Raspbian Buster: https://github.com/ezbik/scripts/tree/master/altnetworking

Answer (score 0):

Same issue,

I tryed to list the available netfilter on my raspberry Pi:

```
ls /lib/modules/5.15.32-v7l+/kernel/net/netfilter/ | grep cg
```

on a proxmox server:

```
 ls /lib/modules/5.15.35-1-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/ | grep cg
xt_cgroup.ko
```

You can build the missing modules, or use Raspberry Pi Ubuntu release, they contain the `xt_cgroup.ko` module out of the box.

and it works