# Route the traffic over specific interface for a process in linux with Cgroups2

Tags: linux, networking, routing, process

I read this way of routing the traffic of a specific interface with Cgroups (Cgroups1): https://superuser.com/a/1048913/1662108

Is there a way of doing the same thing with [Cgroups2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html)?

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot I discovered how:

First the cgroup2 filesystem should be mounted at /sys/fs/cgroup

```
mount -t cgroup2
```

A cgroup must be created:

```
sudo mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/direct
```

The shell must me added to the task list of cgroup, so all the child processes will run inside this cgroup:

```
echo $$ | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/direct/cgroup.procs > /dev/null
```

The cgroup folder must have writing permissions to current user:

```
sudo chown -R "$(id -g -n)":"$(id -g -n)" /sys/fs/cgroup/direct
```

Iptables rules should be added:

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --path direct -j MARK --set-mark 2147483647
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m cgroup --path direct -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

A routing table must be added to iproute2:

```
echo 252 direct | sudo tee -a /etc/iproute2/rt_tables > /dev/null
```

A firewall mark and a additional route must be added:

```
sudo ip rule add fwmark 2147483647 table direct
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table direct dev eth0
```

RP Filter should be disabled:

```
sudo sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

Any program running in this shell will use the additional route and will have its traffic forwarded to **eth0**:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/some/config_file.ovpn
```

Cleaning all the mess:

```
iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -m cgroup --path direct -j MARK --set-mark 2147483647
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -m cgroup --path direct -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ip rule del fwmark 2147483647 table direct
ip route del default via 192.168.1.1 table direct dev eth0
sed -i "/^252\s/d" /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=1
sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/direct/cgroup.procs | while read task_pid; do echo ${task_pid} | tee /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs > /dev/null; done
rmdir /sys/fs/cgroup/direct
```

Comment: In your `mkdir -p` command, I suspect the `-p` is gratuitous.  In your `chown` command, I suspect you want: `chown -R "$(id -u -n)":"$(id -g -n)"` (rather than `-g` twice).